# Error @Html.X() Ext.net in Razor engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ext.net

I got error when I write this code @Html.X().ResourceManager() in view
error message :

*Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'X' and the best extension method overload 'Ext.Net.Extensions.X(System.Web.UI.Page)' has some invalid arguments*

is there a setting that is less ?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This posted code looks to me as a WebForm syntax.

If you are using ASP.NET MVC Razor and the latest Ext.NET v2.x release, you can render all/any of the Ext.NET Components using Razor syntax.

The following sample demonstrates rendering a very simple TabPanel.

```
@{
    Layout = "";    
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Ext.NET Examples</title>
</head>
<body>    
    @Html.X().ResourceManager()

    @(Html.X().TabPanel()
        .Height(300)
        .Items(items => {
            items.Add(Html.X().Panel().Title("Test"));
        }));
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you tell me, where I can download Ext.Net v2.x, because there just  Ext.NET 1.3.0 in http://ext.net/download. or what same if I download from nuget for v2.x beta? thanks.